# How to run function for multitude of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, excel, numpy, scipy

so I need to analyse the peak number & width of a signal (in my case Calcium signal from epidermis cells) that I have stored in an excelsheet. Each column has all the values for one Cell (600 values)

To analyse the peaks, which I will be duing with the `scipy.signal.find_peaks()` and `scipy.signal.peak_widths()` function, I put the individual columns in an 1D numpy array containing all the 601 values from that column.

I did this by saving all the individual columns (Columns are named A, B, C, D, etc in Excelsheet) into their own dataframes (df_A, df_B) then putting them in an array :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

df_A = df.loc[:,'A']
df_B = df.loc[:,'B']

arrA = np.array(df_A)
arrB = np.array(df_B)
```

To calculate the the peak number&width i used the following lines :

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, peak_widths

peaks_A, _ = find_peaks(x,height=7000, prominence= 1)

results_peakwidth_A = peak_widths(x, peaks, rel_height=0.5)
```

Now since I have not only one but > 100 cells/signals to analyse, is there an simple way to do this for all the cells/arrays ? This exceeds my capabilities so I would gladly welcome any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposal would be as follows. In essence you firstly select the required columns (however many there are). Then you create a function that will take in a column (no need to turn it into arrays, unless `scipy` disagrees, in that case add `column = column.values` in the top of `process` function).

Afterwards use apply, which will loop through each column in the dataframe and pass it into the function that you defined.

```
import pandas as pd 
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, peak_widths

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

df = ... # select all columns from A-Z into a single dataframe with the columns required.
# The shape here would b 
# A  B   C 
# 1  4 4.1
# 2  3 4.0
#  ...

# define the function you want to apply to each column 
def process(column):
   peaks, _ = find_peaks(column,height=7000, prominence= 1)
   return peak_widths(column, peaks, rel_height=0.5)

new_columns = df.apply(process)
```

As I'm unsure of what the actual output should look like, you might want to keep the `peaks_A` and the `width`. In which case you could alter the process function slightly:

```py
def process(column):
   peaks, _ = find_peaks(column,height=7000, prominence= 1)
   width = peak_widths(column, peaks, rel_height=0.5)
   return pd.Series({"width": width, "peaks": peaks})
```